# How to configure MassTransit to retry context.Publish() in case of failure?

Tags: c#, masstransit

How to configure MassTransit to retry `context.Publish()` before failing, for example when RabbitMQ server is temporary unavailable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with retry in this context is that the only real reason a `Publish` call would fail is if the broker connection was lost (for any reason: network, etc.).

In that case, the connection which was used to receive the message is also lost, meaning that another node connected to the broker may have already picked up the message. So a retry in this case would be bad, since it would reconnect to the broker and send, but then the message could not be acknowledged (since it was likely picked up on another thread/worker).

The usual course of action here is to let it fail, and when the receive endpoint reconnects, the message will be redelivered to a consumer which will then call `Publish` and reach the desired outcome.

You should make sure that your consumer can handle this (search for *idempotent*) properly to avoid a failure causing a break in your business logic.

#### Updated Jan 2022: Since v7, MassTransit retries all publish/send calls until the cancellationToken is canceled.

Comment: what about `IBus.Publish(...)`? when I am not in a consumer and I want to retry publishing an event... is retry good here and can masstransit handle retry in this state?

Comment: MassTransit will retry publish/send until the cancellationToken is canceled.

Comment: thank you. it is very good option.